# Creation of Struts2 Action classes are restricted when already created threads are put in wait status

Tags: java, struts2

Struts2 Action instance creation is restricted somehow. In my application, I have a main JSP that has 20 iframes (another jsp) in it. Each and every iframe content is loaded from a Action class. There is no problem when I try to load all the 20 frames with 20 action instance creation. When I submit the main JSP, ideally 20 action instances should have been created. But I could see only 6 action instances being created. This application needs the contant of all 20 iframe contents for business processing and hence I am storing it in a vector and I made sure that this vector is accessed by only one action instance at a time. Also I do have wait and notifyAll mechanism implemented. The problem that I face is that only six action instances were created wherein I need 20 action instances to be created. Is this a limitation in Struts2? Is there a way to solve this issue?

```
public void waitForOperationStatus() {
    String opStatus = getOperationStatusFromSession();
    synchronized (productVOsInVector) {
        while (!opStatus.equalsIgnoreCase(SUCCESS)) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Window # " + activeWindowNumber
                        + " Waiting");
                productVOsInVector.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            opStatus = getOperationStatusFromSession();
        }
        productVOsInVector.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more details; it's neither clear what you're actually doing nor what the problem is.

Comment: @ Dave: I figured out that this issue arise due to improper implementation of wait() and notifyAll() mechanism on a vector object.

Comment: Code is given below: Any help to resolve this much appreciated.    public void waitForOperationStatus() {

  String opStatus = getOperationStatusFromSession();  
  synchronized (productVOsInVector) {
   while (!opStatus.equalsIgnoreCase(SUCCESS)) {
    try {
     System.out.println("Window # " + activeWindowNumber + " Waiting");
     productVOsInVector.wait();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    opStatus = getOperationStatusFromSession();
   }
   productVOsInVector.notifyAll();
  }
 }

Comment: Please edit the question; it should be clear that code in comments is essentially illegible.

Comment: I have posted a new question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582316/wait-and-notifyall-mechanism-is-not-working-as-expected-when-the-threads-waiting. Please ignore this question as the issue is no more related to Struts2.