# wait and notifyAll mechanism is not working as expected when the threads waiting on the Vector object is greater than 6

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

There is a requirement in my application wherein 'N' number of Products could be associated with a Quote. The screen layout will have two portions. Top portion has a form that contains quote related information and the bottom portion is meant to hold multiple products. I implemented this functionality by having iframes in the bottom portion. The product will be added/deleted on click of buttons (using javascript). The content to be displayed inside every Product window will be rendered by the same Action (ProductLinesAction.java), JSP (ProductLines.jsp) and other associated resources. The point here is multiple instance of that Action class will be created whenever a new Product window is loaded on the screen. I have no issues in loading the window as it just prepares the form to be displayed. While the quote is to be saved, all these product forms will be submitted and the logic that I incorporated is that 1 to N-1 action instances will put the form values in a VO which is added to a Vector object and saved in session (so that other action instance can take it from session and add on top of it). The N th action instance is meant to save the all these product values collectively. The business rule validation is also performed just before saving and hence the Nth action instance will be made available with the errors which should be displayed in each and every Product window.

Just to make sure that all other action instances also avail the errors corresponding to their window, I implemented the wait and notifyAll mechanism wherein things go awry when more than 6 products are tried to be saved. The code is given below. This piece of code works just fine for products less that or equal to 6 (I mean upto 6 action instances). When the 7th product is loaded and saved, the seventh instance is not at all visible or traceable in debug mode (instance does not reach the intended method upon form submission).

Could anyone throw some light on the mistake that is committed here which is responsible for this issue.

```
public String submitProducts()
        throws Exception {

    String resultValue = "";
    /* Algorithm: */
    // 1. Read the Vector object from Session.
    // 2. Check whether the size of the Vector matches the Total Product windows count.
    // 3. If yes, call the Save operation and remove the list from session.
    // 4. If not, copy the values from current Action instance to VO.
    // 5. Add to List object and place in session.

    synchronized (productVOsInVector) {
        productVOsInVector = getProductVOVectorFromSession();
        if (productVOsInVector == null) {
            productVOsInVector = new Vector <ProductVO>();
        }
        log.info("Window Number is " + activeWindowNumber + ". List size is " + productVOsInVector.size());
        if (productVOsInVector.size() == (prodWindowCount - 1)) {
            productVOsInVector = mapActionToVO(productVOsInVector);
            resultValue = saveOperation(productVOsInVector);
            if (resultValue.equalsIgnoreCase(SUCCESS)) {
                session.put("OperationStatus", SUCCESS);
            }
            session.remove("productVOMapData");
        }
        else {
            if (quoteSaveStatus) {
                quoteSaveStatus = false;
            }
            session.put("OperationStatus", "");
            productVOsInVector = mapActionToVO(productVOsInVector);
            session.put("productVOMapData", productVOsInVector);
        }
        waitForOperationStatus();
    }
    System.out.println("Came out of sync block");
    System.out.println("Action Instance" + activeWindowNumber + " is resuming.");
    // Code to display the Error messages
    return resultValue;
}

public void waitForOperationStatus() {

    String opStatus = getOperationStatusFromSession();
    synchronized (productVOsInVector) {
        if (!opStatus.equalsIgnoreCase(SUCCESS)) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Window # " + activeWindowNumber + " Waiting");
                productVOsInVector.wait();                  
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            opStatus = getOperationStatusFromSession();
        }
        productVOsInVector.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, If you are using Vector, wait/notify or have lots of thread using the same collection, you have serious design issues. I would suggest you use the concurrency library instead starting with ExecutorService for handling asynchronous tasks.

Answer (score 5):

The following is already, by itself, a serious problem:

```
synchronized (productVOsInVector) {
    productVOsInVector = getProductVOVectorFromSession();
    if (productVOsInVector == null) {
        productVOsInVector = new Vector <ProductVO>();
    }
    ...
}
```

You're synchronizing on an object referenced by `productVOsInVector`, and immediately make the reference point to another object. The next thread will thus synchronize on a different object than the first one.

Then you're waiting on this object, and hope that someone will notify you.

I haven't analyzed more than that, but you have a serious design problem. You shouldn't synchronize between threads of the servlet container in the first place. If you have only 6 threads in the pool, and they're all waiting for the 7th one to complete, you have a deadlock. If you have 12 threads in the pool, and 2 clients do that at the same time, you have a deadlock as well. And even if you don't have a deadlock, you make several threads unavailable, doing nothing but wait, hoping that a subsequent HTTP request will notify them. If the last request doesn't come for a reason or another (the user kills his browser, for example, you have 6 threads blocked forever.

My advice is thus: don't mess with threads. Find another way.